# Service Worker caching different size images based on screen resolution

Tags: javascript, caching, service-worker

I want to cache "small_image.png" if screen.width is small and "big_image.png" otherwise.
How can I do that using ServiceWorker?

Code below will throw ReferenceError because screen is not defined in the service worker context.

```
self.addEventListener('install', function(e) {
    e.waitUntil(
        caches.open('stackoverflow').then(function(cache) {
            if(screen.width <= 768){
                return cache.addAll(lowResImages);
            }else{
                return cache.addAll(highResImages);
            }
        })
    );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

That sort of info is available inside of your service worker's `fetch` event, as a request header, if you have the appropriate [Client Hint enabled](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/01/leaner-responsive-images-client-hints/).

As of now, it's not exposed in the `ServiceWorkerGlobalScope` or inside of the event passed to the `install` handler.

Basically, that means you'd be able to [make use](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/09/automating-resource-selection-with-client-hints) of that info if you use runtime caching inside of your `fetch` handler, but not when implementing precaching inside of an `install` handler.